# Google Docs don't open from Finder in High Sierra

Tags: finder, high-sierra, google-docs

Since updating from macOS 10.12 to 10.13, Google Docs links in Finder no longer open in the default browser (or anywhere). Double-clikcing triggers the opening animation, but that's it.

How do I restore the document opening functionality I had in 10.12?